# Placing a Video at Start of GUI to Transition to Main Code Kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

I have a GUI that starts off with a video written in Kivy. That GUI is supposed to then begin loading the whole program in the background while the clip is playing, and after the clip, a window for login is supposed to come up. How do I load the whole program and at the same time load the video to play at the start of the program?

I used event dispatcher but it didn't work.

Additionally, how do I tell the window to open from the video to the login to the first page of the GUI without being separate GUIs to load from?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should first try and convert the video to an image format (gif) and then load it in the Image class in the kv file and then use clock to schedule it to load a new screen(login) after some seconds depending on the duration of the gif